# Replace a word only on specific line # (Regex)

Tags: regex, notepad++

Within a large file I need to replace one word only on specific lines. Say, on line 25, 55, 181, 1448, and so forth about 2000 times.

I started doing it manually using "go to" line and replacing the word. Is there a way to do it automatically, even if I have to change the value for every instance? It will still be faster.

Comment: A better way is to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: @Toto I am sure that is the case, but I wouldn't be asking such stupid questions, if I had the skills to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
\A(?:^.*$\n){5}\K^.*$
```

Where 5 are the previous lines. So 5 means you want to get line number 6.

Working Example:
https://regex101.com/r/QuDon0/1

Comment: `^` and `$` are both useless here, and it will not work with Windows EOL `\r\n`

Comment: '^' and '$' both worked for me in Notepad++ on Windows.